# Passportjs - req.logout function does not exist

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, node.js-connect

I have a route that looks like so:

```
  exports.logout = function(res, req){
      req.logout() // I blow up
      res.redirect('/')
    }
```

> Error: Object #ServerResponse has no method 'logout'

The Request object does not contain a logout function when this route is called. I assume that this is because I have my middleware in the wrong order. Is that correct? This is what my configuration looks like:

```
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.cookieParser('meow'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.session());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(require('less-middleware')({ src: __dirname + '/public' }));
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

Are these passport middleware caveats documented anywhere? The project README gives an example and I have those middleware included in that order but I suspect that another middleware set or use is breaking me. Can anyone shed some light on this for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You accidentally switched your `res` and `req` formal parameters.  Should be:

```
exports.logout = function(req, res){
  req.logout();
  res.redirect('/');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you switched req and res.

```
Error: Object #ServerResponse has no method 'logout'
```

ServerResponse is res not req.